# ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(AC12="X",1,"")"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a Compile error: Syntax error for the following line of code:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(AC12="X",1,"")"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Double each quote inside the string `""X""` and `""""`

Comment: It worked and thank you, but the background is green similar to the shade in AC11, but I want the shading to be "no color".

Comment: It worked and thank you, but the background is green similar to the shade in AC11, but I want the shading to be "no color".    And the formatting are the same.    I would send you a sample but I don't how to in stackoverflow...

Comment: I figured the second part out.  Thank you for all of your help...

Answer (score 1):

You need to double up any quotation marks in the formula string:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(AC12=""X"",1,"""")"
```

Comment: It worked and thank you, but the background is green similar to the shade in AC11, but I want the shading to be "no color". And the formatting are the same. I would send you a sample but I don't how to in stackoverflow...